# Table of users from different sources

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

In this scenario: If I have a table Users, with users from default sign up and facebook sign up.

```
Table users
id | name
1    John (default)
2    Carl (default)
111  Steven (facebook)
...
111  Wayne (default)
```

If the id is auto increment and unique, when the DBMS will try to insert the id 111 from the default sign up, i will get an error due the unique restriction, because the id 111 has inserted manually. So, the DBMS should know if the id 111 exists the next default sign up should be 112 and not 111.

There is any way to avoid this error? Or what is the best practice to handle similar cases?

Make two tables of users seems a bit over-complicated, just to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two alternative approaches.

First, if a user can only sign up in two ways, you can have separate columns for each one.  So, the `users` table would have columns such as:

- DefaultDateTime
- FacebookDateTime

and so on, for whatever columns you want.  When a user registers in the "second" way, then you update the existing record rather than inserting a new one.

The second method is probably better.  Have two tables:

- Users
- Signups

The `Signups` table would have a foreign key relationship back to the `Users` table (possibly with a `NOT NULL` constraint).  Both tables would have auto-incremented integer primary keys.

Apparently, in your data model, the signups are separate from the users, so you should model them separately.  Then you can have as many signups as you like for a given user.

Answer (score 0):

Maby you can try to get the MAX ID value from the database and add +1 to it for the next insert. That way you will always get a value over the current value.